# Is there a way to change the value of a particular index of a string array with dynamic size in C?

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I need to create a program who takes a certain number of rows and columns (from input) and create an array of [rows] strings, each one with [columns] characters (plus the null character '\0'), in C.
So i did this:

```
int R, C;
scanf("%d %d", &R, &C);
int **map = malloc(R * sizeof(*char));
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    map[i] = malloc(C + 1);    //+1 for the null character '\0'
}
//Assign a value for each string (i won't write this, i think is desnecessary, but imagine that all the arrays now have a string value
map[2][3] = 'a';               //This causes an error, probably because a string pointer array have constant value, but how can i do the question request?
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    free(map[i]);
}
free(map);
```

I also tried:

```
int R, C;
scanf("%d %d", &R, &C);
int map[R][C];
//Assign a value for each string
map[2][3] = 'a'                //This works, but in other posts i saw that this way of create an array with dynamic size is wrong
```

So what is the best way to do this, an dynamic array of strings who i can change the value after the first assignment?

Comment: What is the variable N?

Comment: If instead of the unknown variable N you use the variable R then the first code snippet is also correct.

Comment: And I'm inclined to agree with Vlad.  N is unknown in your code snippet, but R is not.

Comment: There's no issue with `map[2][3]` provided the indices are within the bounds
of what you've allocated.

Comment: The issue with `map[2][3]` is that you should check if it is within the bounds of what you have allocated to see if it possible to access it, `if(R>2 && C>3) map[2][3] = 'a';` .

Comment: Sorry, the variable that i used was R, but i got confused. I will edit this.
And [2][3] was just an example, it isn't work even if i get from an correct index.

Answer (score 0):

C99 supports ["Variable-Length Arrays,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) which allows you to declare the array size at runtime.

```
float read_and_process(int n)
{
    float vals[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        vals[i] = read_val();

    return process(n, vals);
}
```

Comment: No, the first way don't worked :( I saw that when you define the value of an array of strings pointers you can't change that, because it's a constant...
But your way worked, thank you!